# What are the list of Fonts used in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to know what are the list of default fonts used by an azure app service.

This is for an app which we have installed on azure app service and its source code does not have any fonts folder.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Md Farid’s response, if you’re looking at rendering custom fonts (system-installed font is used instead) not supported on the standard App Service, because of sandbox restrictions.

Azure App Service provides pre-defined application stacks on Windows like ASP.NET or Node.js, running on IIS. The preconfigured Windows environment locks down the operating system from administrative access, software installations, changes to the global assembly cache, and so on.

This is because, the Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. 
However, using a custom Windows container in App Service lets you make OS changes that your app needs, so it's easy to migrate on-premises app that requires custom OS and software configuration. This tutorial demonstrates how to migrate to App Service an ASP.NET app that uses custom fonts installed in the Windows font library.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-windows-containers-custom-fonts

Also, see sandbox page -https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

Just added an answer here -

it is any web fonts you want, just config in web.config and add the font in a directory in the app service under WWWROOT

[Is it possible to install fonts on an Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858224/is-it-possible-to-install-fonts-on-an-azure-app-service/60210977#60210977)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no such official docs about that , but you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534332/azure-webapp-not-loading-my-fonts) to register mime type in Azure webapp IIS for your own custom fonts files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mount the storage like in that ticket: [Azure Linux App Service with .Net Core Stack. Unable to use NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340545/azure-linux-app-service-with-net-core-stack-unable-to-use-nodejs/65703307#65703307)

[image: Azure Portal]